# How can I set max value of Y-axis dynamically in Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am using prometheus and grafana together.
When I show the load1, load5, and load15 metrics, I want to dynamically set the max value of the y axis to the number of cpu. Is there any way to dynamically set the y axis in the grafana graph when the graph is plotted?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, and it is possible for load average to be higher than the number of cores.

Comment: I've circumvented this problem by bypassing it in some other way. I have drawn the lines representing the number of cores together on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use variables in the Min/Max fields of the axis. If so, **there is no official support for this.** You can check the status for this feature at: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3935

**Possible workaround:** someone suggested a patch in the comments of the issue I mentioned: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3935#issuecomment-403503102

Maybe it will work for you.